# terminology for the derivative of a trajectory in phase space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have 2nd order ODE.  For example: $x'' + x = 0.$
We can view this as a first order ODE in two dimensions:

$x' = v$

$v' = -x$

What is the vector $(x', v') = (v, -x)$ called?

Answer (score 1):

When working with a system $\vec{x}'=f(\vec x)$, I call $\vec{x}'$ the *velocity vector*. And I am [not alone](http://math.berkeley.edu/~simic/Spring12/Math1B/systems.pdf) (middle of first page). The idea is that $\vec x$ is the position vector of a point in the phase space, so the derivative naturally corresponds to velocity.

This may be awkward when you also think of $v$ as velocity of point at position $x$, as in your example. But you have to decide: do you want to think about second-order equation, or about the equivalent first-order system? If it's the latter, then you forget the original meaning of $x$ and $v$ and think of $(x,v)$ as coordinates of a point, with velocity $(x',v')$.